# Normal values not changing while chang normal in bmesh obje

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine, blend-files

I am using blender 2,79 and blender API to edit my mesh. Following is the my code..

```
import bpy, mathutils
import bmesh, os, sys
from bpy import context

path = bpy.data.filepath;
folder, name = os.path.split(path);

bm = bmesh.new()
meshes = [o.data for o in context.selected_objects
            if o.type == 'MESH']

#file = open(folder+'/norma.txt', "w")
#sys.stdout = file
def print_vertices(mesh_b, mesh_a):
    bm_b = bmesh.new();
    bm_a = bmesh.new();
    bm_b.from_mesh(mesh_b);
    bm_a.from_mesh(mesh_a);
    vs_b = [v_b.co for v_b in bm_b.verts]
    vs_a = [v_a.co for v_a in bm_a.verts]
    file = open(folder+'/vertices.txt', "w")
    sys.stdout = file
    for k in range(len(vs_b)):
        print('before', vs_b[k]);
        print('after', vs_a[k]);
        print('\n');
    print('Finished');
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ #reset
    file.close()

def print_normals(mesh_b, mesh_a):
    bm_b = bmesh.new();
    bm_a = bmesh.new();
    bm_b.from_mesh(mesh_b);
    bm_a.from_mesh(mesh_a);
    fn_b = [f_b.normal for f_b in bm_b.faces]
    fn_a = [f_a.normal for f_a in bm_a.faces]
    file = open(folder+'/norma.txt', "w")
    sys.stdout = file
    for k in range(len(fn_b)):
        print('before', fn_b[k]);
        print('after', fn_a[k]);
        print('\n');
    print('Finished');
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ #reset
    file.close()

mesh = meshes[0].copy();
bm.from_mesh(mesh)
#bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
#bmesh.ops.recalc_face_normals(bm, faces=bm.faces)
if hasattr(bm.verts, "ensure_lookup_table"): 
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table();
    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table();
    bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table();

for v in bm.verts:
    v.co.x = v.co.x + 2;
    v.co.y = v.co.y + 2;
    v.co.z = v.co.z + 2;
    #v.co.x +=0.2;
    #print('x is updated');
for f in bm.faces:
    nl = f.normal.length;
    if nl < 1:
        #fn = mathutils.Vector()
        #fn = f.normal*4;
        print('before', f.normal);
        f.normal = f.normal * 0.2;
        print('after', f.normal);
        print('\n');
bm.normal_update();
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
mesh.update()

#meshes[0] = mesh.copy();
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
#bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
#bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh, True)
bm.clear()
bm.free()

print_normals(meshes[0], mesh);
print_vertices(meshes[0], mesh);

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
```

When i Save the normal and vertices value to file. Than vertices have been changed while the normal not.. Can any body tell me how to change the value of normals ??

One may consider any built in mesh like Monkey in blender. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A normal is a  **unit** length direction vector.  Looking for normals with length less than one and trying to set length to 0.2 ... most likely wont work as expected. Only the  zero vector cannot be normalized.

Comment: Ok.. thanks for your reply. But in blender when I open mesh in edit mode and then show the face normal with increase the normal size  shows its effect than why not in script...?? Can you guide me a little bit more ?.

Comment: To repeat it's a direction vector. For example the positive x axis direction can be represented by an infinite amount of vectors `Vector((a, 0, 0))` where `a > 0`  The single  unit length vector is (1, 0, 0).  As per "but" example: You are not adjusting the normal value, just its display size.